# JavaScript ES7 - Call async function at top of page, await at bottom

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I'm comfortable with regular async/await functions, but I'm looking for something a little more complex.

I want to make an async AJAX call at the top of the page, while that's fetching, continue loading the rest of the page, but at the bottom, or after page load, start another JS function that awaits for the initial call made earlier to complete & use the data.

The motivation is pretty simple, right? Start off the async AJAX call, in the meantime load the rest of the page, then use the data when all the HTML, CSS, Images, etc, has loaded.  Or am I overlooking something simple & obvious?

I'm willing to fall back on Promises if necessary, but still not clear to me how to do it.

Thanks for any thoughts...

Chris

Comment: this is a simple xhr call, what's the problem?

Comment: async functions return promises. just store it in a variable and await it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top of the page:

```
const pendingResult = fetch(someUrl);
```

End of the page:

```
pendingResult.then(result=>console.log("result is:",result));
```

Or if you want to use `async/await`:

```
async function doSomethingWithResult(){
  const result = await pendingResult;
  //....
}
doSomethingWithResult();
```

Comment: Ah, nice approach!  I came up with a more clumsy approach combining jQuery at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

I think HMR has a more elegant solution so I select that, but I found this works also, if someone wants a different approach:

At top of page (after axios & jQuery are loaded)

```
(async function() {
  var aresponse = await axios.get("/ajax"); //Make the AJAX call at start
  $(function () {
    //Do something with aresponse after page/dom is fully loaded
  });
})();
// Rest of page
```

This also lets you combine all your JS in a single minified JS file you can include at the top of your page, if that's your thing...